# Why docker container can't find python handler module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I am running my *python(2.7)* application inside a docker container. I am using python `dictconfig` for the logging configuration of the application.

The base of the application image is `ubuntu:14.04`. `Python` and `pip` is working is perfectly.

But when I try to run the container I get error messages like 
`Cannot resolve 'logging.handlers.FileHandler': No module named FileHandler`. Same error shows up for `StreamHandler` and `SysLogHandler`.

But if I comment the logging *config* part, application runs perfectly.

What additional configuration is needed to make logging work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to configure logging driver when you run the container

```
--log-driver=syslog
```

You can find more on here.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/